# Failed to install Tensorflow 1.12, Python 3.6.2 on Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, windows-7

On Windows 7, I would like to use Keras with Python to build Neural Networks but I'm getting the following error while installing Keras with Tensorflow (see python log of error at the end):

> ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

It seems very difficult due to the various dependencies of software components. Some posts recommend to use CNTK with Keras but I would like to learn Tensorflow.

If it's possible then any idea would be highly appreciated.

My configuration (I have installed the packages using "pip"):

- Window 7
- Python 3.6.3
- pip 18.1
- Keras 2.2.4
- Tensorflow 1.12.0
- Tensorflow-gpu 1.10.0 (downgrade recommended by some on the forum)
- CUDA 9.0
- cudnn64_7.dll
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistribuable (x64)
  14.0.23026 (+ 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013)

Note that CUDA v9.0 installer reported some issues linked to Visual Studio:

---

Installed:
    - Nsight Monitor and HUD Launcher

Not Installed:
Nsight for Visual Studio 2017 Reason: VS2017 was not found
Nsight for Visual Studio 2015 Reason: VS2015 was not found
Nsight for Visual Studio 2013 Reason: VS2013 was not found
Nsight for Visual Studio 2012 Reason: VS2012 was not found
Nsight for Visual Studio 2010 Reason: VS2010 was not found

---

Finally here is the output of python while trying to use Keras:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras1.py", line 2, in 
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from . import utils
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from . import conv_utils
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
    from .. import backend as K
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in 
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "D:\install\python363\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: Could this be the issue: https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/developers/ir9Lgi27eg4/s-X4NcO1BQAJ

Comment: I'm still failing to install Tensorflow. But anyway I have just installed ctnk and it works fine at the first time. So I can only recommend cntk instead of Tensorflow for Windows 7.